# How to apply KMeans to get the centroid using dataframe with multiple features

Tags: python, dataframe, k-means, euclidean-distance

I am following this detailed KMeans tutorial: https://github.com/python-engineer/MLfromscratch/blob/master/mlfromscratch/kmeans.py which uses dataset with 2 features.

But I have a dataframe with 5 features (columns), so instead of using the `def euclidean_distance(x1, x2):` function in the tutorial, I compute the euclidean distance as below.

```
def euclidean_distance(df):
    n = df.shape[1]
    distance_matrix = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            distance_matrix[i,j] = np.sqrt(np.sum((df.iloc[:,i] - df.iloc[:,j])**2))
    return distance_matrix
```

Next I want to implement the part in the tutorial that computes the centroid as below;

```
def _closest_centroid(self, sample, centroids):
    distances = [euclidean_distance(sample, point) for point in centroids]
```

Since my `def euclidean_distance(df):` function only takes 1 argument, df, how best can I implement it in order to get the centroid?

My sample dataset, df is as below:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
0.54,0.68,0.46,0.98,-2.14
0.52,0.44,0.19,0.29,30.44
1.27,1.15,1.32,0.60,-161.63
0.88,0.79,0.63,0.58,-49.52
1.39,1.15,1.32,0.41,-188.52
0.86,0.80,0.65,0.65,-45.27
```

[**Added: plot() function**]

The plot function you included gave an error **TypeError: object of type 'itertools.combinations' has no len()**, which I fixed by changing `len(combinations)` to `len(list(combinations))`. However the output is **[image: output.png]** is not a scatter plot. Any idea on what I need to fix here?

Comment: the euclidean distance function in your tutorial is defined for arrays, so the dimensionality of the space does not matter. This means you don't need to write your own function.

Comment: The function in the tutorial is for two arrays with an arbitrary number of features (what I meant by dimensionality in my earlier comment). It infers the number of features from the shape of the dataset. Where exactly do you get an error when running the code from the tutorial?

Comment: line 81, in _closest_centroid
    `distances = [euclidean_distance(sample, point) for point in centroids]`
**TypeError: euclidean_distance() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)**

Comment: the function in the repo would not throw that error, because it does take 2 arguments. Are you sure you are using that one?

Comment: When I use the tutorial function, the **kmeans_test.py** on **line 17: y_pred = k.predict(X)** throws **'ValueError: Unrecognized marker style [13.15717]'** pointing to **lines 35** and **93** on the **kmeans.py** file. As mentioned, I change **make_blobs()** function to cater for my dataframe with 31 rows and 5 columns(features) as below. Otherwise the tutorial code runs fine without any modifications.

`data = pd.read_csv('df.csv')`
`X = np.array(data)`
`print(X.shape)`
`clusters = 5` 
`k = KMeans(K=clusters, max_iters=150, plot_steps=True)`
`y_pred = k.predict(X)`
`k.plot()`

Comment: How are they different?

Comment: Thanks the elbow method is fixed...I have edited the question regarding your plot function, which I think could help me but is not giving the correct scatter plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the data and clustering it should not throw any errors, even when you increase the number of features in the dataset.
In fact, you only get an error in that part of the code when you redefine the euclidean_distance function.

This asnwer addresses the actual error of the plotting function that you are getting.

> ```
>    def plot(self):
>       fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
>
>        for i, index in enumerate(self.clusters):
>            point = self.X[index].T
>            ax.scatter(*point)
> ```

takes all points in a given cluster and tries to make a scatterplot.

the asterisk in `ax.scatter(*point)` means that point is unpacked.

The implicit assumption here (and this is why this might be hard to spot) is that `point` should be 2-dimensional. Then, the individual parts get interpreted as x,y values to be plotted.

But since you have 5 features, point is 5-dimensional.

Looking at [the docs of ax.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html):

> ```
> matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter
> Axes.scatter(self, x, y, s=None, c=None, marker=None, cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None,
> verts=<deprecated parameter>, edgecolors=None, *, plotnonfinite=False,
> data=None, **kwargs)
> ```

so ,the first few arguments that ax.scatter takes (other than self) are:

```
x 
y
s (i.e. the markersize)
c (i.e. the color)
marker (i.e. the markerstyle)
```

the first four, i.e. x,y, s anc c allow floats, but your dataset is 5-dimensional, so the fifth feature gets interpreted as marker, which expects a MarkerStyle. Since it is getting a float, it throws the error.

#### what to do:

only look at 2 or 3 dimensions at a time, or use dimensionality reduction (e.g. principal component analysis) to project the data to a lower-dimensional space.

For the first option, you can redefine the plot method within the KMeans class:

```
def plot(self):
    

    import itertools
    combinations = itertools.combinations(range(self.K), 2) # generate all combinations of features
    
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8), nrows=len(combinations), ncols=1) # initialise one subplot for each feature combination

    for (x,y), ax in zip(combinations, axes.ravel()): # loop through combinations and subpltos
        
        
        for i, index in enumerate(self.clusters):
            point = self.X[index].T
            
            # only get the coordinates for this combination:
            px, py = point[x], point[y]
            ax.scatter(px, py)

        for point in self.centroids:
            
            # only get the coordinates for this combination:
            px, py = point[x], point[y]
            
            ax.scatter(px, py, marker="x", color='black', linewidth=2)

        ax.set_title('feature {} vs feature {}'.format(x,y))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks so much @warped. I am now able to cluster using 2 dimensions using the original tutorial (however, your plot(self) function above executes but only plots black rectangles and not clusters). I also tried PCA to reduce 5 the features to 2 dimensions and was able to get the clustering working.

Comment: @Gee you can use ax.plot instead of ax.scatter

Comment: @Gee could you edit this into your question or ask a new one? this is a bit tedious to read in a comment

Comment: any idea how I can get the plot() method you suggested above to plot the clusters? I have tried it several times but it does not plot the clusters.